# Getting simple styles to work with react arrow functions

Tags: reactjs

I appreciate this may be a little basic here, but I'm relatively new to React and am testing the waters with various ways of applying on-the-fly styling rather than creating separate stylesheets and importing them.

I'm trying to experiment adding styles to three different elements - one via inline styles, another via a style tag, and another via a style variable - where only the inline style seems to work.

Here is my code with all 3 elements:

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  render {
    const testOneStyle = {
      color: "red",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <span style={testOneStyle} className="test-one">test 1</span>
        <span className="test-two">test 2</span>
        <style>
          .test-two {
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold
          }
        </style>
        <span style={{color: "red"}} className="test-three">test 3</span>
      </div>
    )
  } 
}

export default App
```

Firstly, does the variable style (i.e. [here](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp)) only work with class components rather than functional components?

And can someone explain why this is not rendering and how to render and apply the styles?

Thank you for any advice. Here is a StackBlitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tjukup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `<style>` tags don't work in JSX the way they do in html. You are going to have to parse the the string appropriately yourself, since JSX is just javascript with syntactical sugar to convert into `React.createElement()` function with the right parameters. So you want to generally avoid `style` and `head` tags in JSX, but if you do, you want to use it like:

```
<style>
{"\
     .test-two {\
       color: red;\
       font-weight: bold;\
     }\
"}
</style>
```

**EDIT**

Also, to answer your question "does the variable style only work with class components rather than functional components?", **no**. The *prop* `style` is a JSX prop and works regardless of what kind of component you are using.

**EDIT**

And the reason why your component is not rendering, is because `render()` is a function that is only used in **class based components**. In a functional component you just directly return the JSX.

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const testOneStyle = {
    color: "red",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span style={testOneStyle} className="test-one">
        test 1 - fails
      </span>
      <span className="test-two">test 2 - fails</span>
      <style>
        {`
          .test-two {
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold
          }
        `}
      </style>
      <span style={{ color: "red" }} className="test-three">
        test 3 - works
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**EDIT**

As you may have observed in the snippet I have provided, you can also use strings with "`" to make it easier to enter strings in JSX

Comment: Good answer. Maybe an explanation would be nice about the precedence of `style` over `className`. Also, avoiding the usage of `<style>` tag should be emphasized multiple times :)

Comment: I just assumed that the user knows that the precedence of inline styles is the highest. And yeah, I really should emphasise that it is not recommended to use style tags anyway. Perhaps I need a 5th edit?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may helps you

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const testOneStyle = {
    color: "blue",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <span style={testOneStyle} className="test-one">
        test 1 - fails
      </span>
      <span className="test-two">
        test 2 - fails
      </span>
      <style>
        {
          `.test-two {
          color: green;
          font-weight: bold
          }`
        }
      </style>
      <span style={{color: "red"}} className="test-three">
        test 3 - works
      </span>
    </div>
  )
} 

export default App
```

Explaination:

You are using [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

Class component require `render` method to return a JSX. Functional component can directly return JSX.

you can add style tag in your JSX but the context inside need to be string.